# How to fix Parameter missing error in Twilio OTP API?

Tags: api, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to Send OPT using `Twilio API` with AIOX but I am getting missing parameter error in response. I tried with same with PHP but getting same error. Is any help help me on this?

Please check my below code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const accountSid = 'your_account_sid';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const serviceSid = 'your_verify_service_sid';

export default {
  methods: {
    async generateSmsOtp(phoneNumber) {
      const response = await axios.post(`https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/${serviceSid}/Verifications`, {
        To: phoneNumber,
        Channel: 'sms',
      }, {
        auth: {
          username: accountSid,
          password: authToken,
        },
      });

      return response.data.sid;
    },
  },
};
```

Getting Below Error:

```
{
  "code": 60200,
  "message": "Invalid parameter",
  "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200",
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to URL-encode the payload and cannot just send them as you did. You can use [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) to fix this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import qs from 'qs';

const accountSid = 'your_account_sid';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const serviceSid = 'your_verify_service_sid';

export default {
  methods: {
    async generateSmsOtp(phoneNumber) {
      const response = await axios.post(`https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/${serviceSid}/Verifications`, qs.stringify({
        To: phoneNumber,
        Channel: 'sms',
      }), {
        auth: {
          username: accountSid,
          password: authToken,
        },
      });

      return response.data.sid;
    },
  },
};
```

**But I'd recommend using the [Twilio client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio)** instead of axios and qs. With that, the code should look as follows:

```js
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.verify.v2.services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                .verifications
                .create({to: '+15017122661', channel: 'sms'})
                .then(verification => console.log(verification.status));
```

PS: You can find more examples in the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/quickstarts/node-express).